# Why is Duplicity asking for a passphrase when restoring a backup?

Tags: deja-dup, duplicity

I'm migrating from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. I've got everything from 16.04 backed up via Deja-dup to an external disk. Now after I installed 18.04, I tried restoring it but failed. So I proceeded to try Duplicity.

The problem is, Duplicity is asking for GnuPG passphrase even though I know exactly that I didn't set one up when creating the backups. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me as well.

tldr; try a space character for the passphrase

Most of below may not actually be relevant, but I'm not sure what causes the problem, so here is what I did:

- I previously made a backup using the Backups GUI built in to Ubuntu (I think it's really called deja-dup), then I wiped my machine
- After the 18.04 install I configured Backups to backup the current data to a new folder
- I tried to use Backups restore feature to restore my original backup to a temp folder, but for some reason it would only restore from the new backup
- I then decided to use duplicity directly like so...
- `duplicity restore file://. /<my path>/temp_dir`
- but it asked for a passphrase, I simply hit `Enter`, but it asked again
- I started searching for answers and found this question... I found no answers
- In a fit of desperation I tried a space character... and it worked!

It's some sort of bug I guess, my restore is still running so I'm not currently sure if any input would work or only a space.

Hope it helps

Comment: I can confirm this. I just put in a variation of my usual password and it works.